# App Crashes in iOS 5.0 simulator but not in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

I've developed a simple app TabViewController app with two UITableViewController Views initially testing in the iOS 6 simulator and it all works fine as it should.  One view is a list of options and the other is a list you can add/remove items to.

I decided to test in the iOS 5.0 simulator and when I attempt to segue from the UITableViewController to my custom view where I fill in the details for the item to be added the app throws an exception with no errors in the console, just lots of confusing (to me) numbers and letters etc when you select the thread where the exception has been thrown in Debug Nav... (about 5-10 times the amount below)

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0xec3cde:  pushl  %ebp
0xec3cdf:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0xec3ce1:  pushl  %ebx
0xec3ce2:  pushl  %edi
0xec3ce3:  pushl  %esi
0xec3ce4:  subl   $2028, %esp
0xec3cea:  calll  0xec3cef                  ; objc_exception_throw + 17
0xec3cef:  popl   %edi
0xec3cf0:  movl   $16, (%esp)
0xec3cf7:  calll  0xed8840                  ; symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception
...
```

My question is why is this likely to be?  Surely if I was using something that was iOS 6 only it wouldn't let me build?  I've changed all the targets that I could find to be iOS 5.0 rather than iOS 6.0 and am now just confused.

Does anyone have any idea or any pointers for what I need to do or search for?

Comment: Is AutoLayout enabled in your storyboard?

Comment: ah, it is yes.  Thanks!  Now getting unwind unavailable in iOS 6.0, back to google I go :)

Comment: I have added this as an answer, please accept it if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that AutoLayout is not enabled in your storyboard.

[image]

AutoLayout is iOS6 only.